# How do I secure an Azure Mobile Service with Azure AD? ADAL.JS

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, adal

I have created an application in my Azure AD. I switch into the Mobile Service and go to the identity tab. For MS identity is asks for a client ID. I found the Client ID in the Azure AD configure tab.

However, I had no idea what to use for Client Secret and Package SID. It seems like it is expecting you are using a Windows Store app to access the service rather than a Javascript app which is what I am working with.

So, my question is, how do you secure an Azure Mobile Service with Azure AD when an AngularJS web application is accessing the service?

(I don't want to use google, because I want to control the users that can access this, so I will manually add the users to the Azure AD that I want to grant access to the service.)

UPDATE:

Per the answer below I have attempted to use ADAL.JS. It is "mostly working" with the following issues.

1. Chrome locks up tight - it doesn't work.
2. When using a Microsoft Account added to my Azure AD domain, it just goes into a loop and keeps redirecting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mobile Service Identity configuration, for Azure AD as you ask, following parameters are requested

- App URL
- Client ID
- Allowed Tenants

Package SID is related to MSA account authentication. Azure AD is last at the bottom.

Refer to: [Register your apps to use an Azure Active Directory Account login](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication)

In Azure AD, you need to have created an application, that matches the Client ID and App ID URI with the information in the Mobile Service side.

Other important information to fill in here:

- Reply URL: you should have an entry with the URI of your web application (hosting Angular)
- Allow *Enable single sign-on and read users' profiles* as Delegated Permission
- Allow OAuth implicit flow by editing and updating the application manifest file

For more detailed steps to follow, especially about last item in my list, look at this sample
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet and its README

Once you've obtained the access token via ADAL.JS libraries, then you can use it to call login method of Mobile Service just providing the right authentication provider name, and the access token retrieved with ADAL.JS

Using ADAL.JS instead of Mobile Services SDK for obtaining the access token gives you also the refresh token back, which you can cache and store for automatic access token renewal; avoiding to have the user entering credentials every time

Comment: thanks. I just couldn't find this info. My google fu failed me.

Comment: It is possible to test this when running the angular app on localhost? Also, I'm using a javascript mobile service if that matters.

Comment: Yes, sure. It should be enough to add `http://localhost:<yourport>` as additional Redirect URI. Note also http is possible in this case

Comment: So, I hit my app, it redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf but when I type in my username it says redirecting to microsoft login. (just in like a loop) Am I not able to use my Ms account which is a user in my domain and granted access to the Azure AD app I set up in that domain? I just created a user, and that seems to work. Although it isn't sending bearer header with the XHR traffic.

Comment: How are you testing the JS backend locally? For the real service try adding `https://<yourservice>.azure-mobile.net/login/aad` as Redirect URI. If this solves, I'll update my answer. Try then using your service/APIs straight from a browser.

Comment: I  mean, I'm running the AngularJS app locally, of course I am hitting the cloud mobile services.

Comment: In IE a domain created users works, my MS user id just goes into some loop. this is in IE.

In chrome, it just hangs chrome like it in some redirect storm.

Also, the ADAL.Js doesn't seem to be sending the bearer auth header. I get a 401 when I set the permissions on the table to Authenticated User. Perhaps it doesn't work with UI router?

Comment: You must call _login_ on the mobile service client anyway, and passing there 'aad' as provider, and the access token. The sample also uses route, or I've seen some samples using it for sure

Comment: Ok, adding that url as a redirect in the ADAL.Js configuration (I assume that's what you meant) causes it to want to download done.json after I log in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78844/discussion-between-pilotbob-and-massimo-prota).

Comment: Looks like IE is sending an Auth cookie rather than Auth header... and Mobile services kicks back a 401.