# How can I get the JWT access_token after loging in with ADAL.js?

Tags: javascript, adal

I see that adal.idtoken is stored in the cache. However, it doesn't look like a JWT which is what I think I need to pass to my azure mobile service to get a AUMO auth token.

Comment: This might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30646217/181108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retrieve cached tokens programmatically, see AuthenticationContext.prototype.getCachedToken from https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/master/lib/adal.js. All the tokens issued by Azure AD are JWT tokens.

Comment: thanks, I realized this was the case. For some reason the Azure Mobile Service is rejecting the token when I post it to the /login/aad endpoint per the docs so I thought maybe the idtoken in the cache wasn't actually a JWT.

Comment: I am using the adal-angular.js service.. it seems getCachedToken won't get the endpoints token if it hasn't been retrieved. So, I am using adalService.acquireToken(resource) if getCachedToken doesn't return a token. I assume that is correct.

Comment: Yep, in the answer I assumed you wanted to access a token already present. If you still need to retrieve it, acquiretoken is the right one... Provided that there is an active session in place with AAD

Comment: Thanks, does acquireToken look in the cache first? Or should I always check the cache first before calling acquireToken?

Comment: I adal.js takes care of it for you, put a breakpoint (adal.js) AuthenticationContext.prototype.getCachedToken = function (resource) {